# Align <a> to right side of div

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, dom, material-ui

How would I align the `<a>` element, containing the Button with the string `Push Me` to the right side of the `<div>` (`<Paper>`)?

https://codesandbox.io/s/eager-noyce-j356qe

The application is in `demo.tsx` file.

Note: I cannot set the position of the button to `absolute` and then position it `right: 0px` because I need to adjust the height of the `<div>` (`<Paper>`) according to its content, which includes the height of the `<Button>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your demo i'd suggest you'd wrap the text in a `<div>` and give `display: flex` property for your `<Paper>`. Then you could use `flex-gow: 2` on that `div`

```
<Paper style={{ display: 'flex' }}>
  <div style={{ flexGrow: '2' }}>
    <p>This is some text </p>
    <p>This is even more text </p>
  </div>
  <Link
    component="button"
    variant="body2"
    onClick={() => {
      console.info("I'm a button.");
    }}
  >
    <Button
      variant='contained'>
      Push Me
    </Button>
  </Link>
</Paper>
```

Here's the forked [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/dazzling-beaver-080zsb?file=/demo.tsx)

[More](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox) about flexbox if you're not familiar with it

Comment: Thanks, I am familiar with flex box. I thought there might be a way around it...